# Getting CORS error when communicating with Azure HTTP-triggered function v3 in docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, cors, azure-functions

My docker `.env` file (environment definition file) has the following environment variable to accommodate incoming Web API calls from an angular app:

```
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS='["http://localhost:4200"]'
```

The way that this Azure Function App v3 defined in the docker compose file is per the following snippet:

```
myhttpfunction:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}httptriggeredfunc
    container_name: azurefunctions
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: app/HttpFunctions/Dockerfile
    environment: 
      - CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS
    ports: 
      - 9080:80
```

I am able to send web requests to the function app by POSTMAN but the angular app fails due to the following error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:9080/api/GetData' from
> origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy:
> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource.

What is the solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently we need to incorporate a reverse proxy to get around this issue per [this Github post](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/5090).

Answer (score 1):

(a yer late but .. better late than never)

see Microsoft MVP Eduard Keilholz's excellent deep dive [Container Apps - Struggling with CORS (part 4)](https://hexmaster.nl/posts/container-apps-cors-settings/)

solution:

```
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS=["http://localhost:4200"]
CONTAINER_NAME=bananas
```

Comment: The solution is to setup a reverse proxy like nginx.

Comment: or just add the CONTAINER_NAME, yes. Tested and verified.